# Naming dataframes from the loop

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a properly working function and would like to add the naming of DF while looping.

There is a function:

```
def(function1)
v0 = (x,y,z)
v1 = (aa,bb,cc)

for link, name in zip(v0,v1)
df = function1(v0)
```

It seems there is an issue as I cannot pass the variable from the loop to the data frame name.

The result I want to achieve:

```
df.aa from function1(x)
df.bb from function1(y)
df.cc from function1(z)
```

Comment: That's not a valid python function, and you cannot call functions using `from`... Perhaps you should be using a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would want to use a dictionary to store named results of a function call

```
def foo(x):
    return some_dataframe

v0 = (x,y,z)
v1 = ('aa' , 'bb' , 'cc')

data = dict() 
for v, name in zip(v0,v1):
    data[name] = foo(v)
```

Comment: I will try to do it with dictionaries.